# Setup basic socket.io with Svelte/Vite

Tags: socket.io, svelte

So recently I started messing around with Svelte and ran into an issue setting up a socket.io server

so far I have simple web server setup with svelte-adapter-node and I have the socket.io client stuff setup.

here's my current setup

```java
// server.js
import { handler } from './build/handler.js';
import express from 'express';
const app = express();
import http from "http";
const server = http.createServer(app);
import { Server } from "socket.io";
var io = new Server(server).listen(server);

app.use(handler);

io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    console.log("A user connected");

    socket.on("disconnected", function () {
        console.log("A user disconnected");
    });
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on port 3000');
});
```

It gives the `http://localhost:3000/socket.io?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nudyw9R` error in the browser

Comment: Adapters are not used during development (aka npx svelte-kit dev). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67407879/registering-socket-io-to-vite-for-sveltekit/69243938 for getting socket io working inside vite.